# I have a doubt on taking pad dimensions in this below picture what is the pad width and height.any body kindly clear my doubt

Tags: pcb-design

[image]
See this picture and kindly clear my doubt thanks for your help

Comment: These are pin dimensions, _recommended_ pad dimensions may be different. As I do not see this guideline in any AD datasheet with similar packages, and even in package description document https://www.analog.com/media/en/package-pcb-resources/package/pkg_pdf/lfcspcp/cp_24_14.pdf there must be some additional document explaining pad dimensioning in overall for such packages.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you are looking for the *land pattern* (PCB footprint), then I believe this is the one you should use:

[image]

I performed a search for the Analog Devices package name and was able to find another of their components that used it, but actually included the land pattern in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adl5566.pdf).

In addition, Analog Devices application note AN-772 contains the information used to calculate the land pattern pad sizes:

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-772.pdf?doc=ADL5566.pdf